DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN while Using Mobile Hotspot
I'm encountering a very strange issue. My website (https://bklg.org) is reachable on mobile networks using a web browser, but when you try to reach it over a personal hotspot users are receiving a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error.
I've had users report this, and I replicated it myself on my iPhone.
Users rely on moble hotspots to access the site and I can't figure out why the DNS lookup would fail only while using a mobile hotspot. This worked up until recently, and I haven't made any changes to the DNS records for over a year. When I check the DNS propagation it is definitely propagated. When I navigate to my site on my phone using the mobile network the site is reachable.
Does anyone have any insight into this? Is there anything I can do about it?
